# UsatisfiedLinkError while using BridJ with Android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, bridj

Currently I am using *BRIDj-0.6.1-android.jar* for Android. The problem is that the library shows an unsatisfied link error as follows:

```
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589):    at org.bridj.BridJ.getRuntimeByRuntimeClass(BridJ.java:233)
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589):    at org.bridj.BridJ.getRuntime(BridJ.java:264)
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589):    at org.bridj.BridJ.register(BridJ.java:287)
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589):    at org.bridj.BridJ.register(BridJ.java:161)
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589):    at com.g5.jna.crypto.LibcryptoLibrary.<clinit>(LibcryptoLibrary.java:20)
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589):    ... 6 more
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589):    at org.bridj.CRuntime.<clinit>(CRuntime.java:450)
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589):    ... 13 more
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sizeOf_ptrdiff_t
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589):    at org.bridj.Platform.sizeOf_ptrdiff_t(Native Method)
09-27 17:51:58.740: E/AndroidRuntime(12589):    at org.bridj.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:149)
```

I have kept *libcrypto.so* file in *lib/armeabi/* path of my Android project.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an opened issue about this:
https://github.com/ochafik/nativelibs4java/issues/335

Comment: The problem should be fixed in the latest 0.6.3-SNAPSHOT, and I'll publish a 0.6.3 release soon :-)